# Python struct not accepting 0xf031 as unsigned short

Tags: python-3.x, struct, protocols

So I'm trying to implement a serial line data protocol. One of the commands has hex value 0xf031 (61489 in integer) .

When I try to enter it in as a unsigned short value in a struct I get this as an output:

```
d1= 61489
d2 = 24
pack('<HH', d1, d2)

>> b'1\xf0\x18\x00'
```

I expect

```
b'\x31\xf0\x18\x00'
```

With some trail and error I found out that the highest value it accepts is 61448

```
d1= 61448
d2 = 24

print(pack('<HH', d1, d2))

>> b'\x08\xf0\x18\x00'
```

Have anyone any tips or tricks. Even If i split the two bytes and enter them as single bytes using B (unsigned char) i get the same result.

```
d1= hex(61489)
d2 = 24
#print(d1)
d1_1 = d1[2:4]
d1_2 = d1[4:]

print(pack('<BBH', int(d1_1, base=16), int(d1_2,base = 16), d2))

>> b'\xf01\x18\x00'
```

And again the value 61448 gives correct bytes.

Just to show what 61449 gives me

```
d1= hex(61449)
d2 = 24
#print(d1)
d1_1 = d1[2:4]
d1_2 = d1[4:]

print(pack('<BBH', int(d1_1, base=16), int(d1_2,base = 16), d2))

>> b'\xf0\t\x18\x00'
```

Im using Jupyter-Lab in pipenv. python 3.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing what you should be seeing. The `1` in the b-string isn't the value 1, it's the ASCII character "1" (0x31). b-strings will represent as printable characters when possible.

You can see if you convert it back that the original value is still there (in decimal):

```
>>> unpack('<H', pack('<H', 0xf031))
(61489,)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, come to think of it I have seen this with python before.

Comment: you (@KarlNorway) are not paying attention to the bytes representation of the packed data you are getting: for bytes that fall in ASCII range, i.e., with values from 32 to 127 (dec), you see the character itself , instead of it \xHH escape code. So, `b'1\xf0` is _actually_ just a representation of `b'\x31\xf0'`, but with the digit "1" shown instead of the escape code "`\x31`".  Use the method `.hex()` from bytes objects to view each value as 2-hexadecimal digits, regardless of their ASCII representation: `b'1\xf0\x18\x00'.hex()` -> `'31f01800'`