# Bytes representation in Python

Tags: python

I need to do some work with bytes in Python and I've come across a byte string I don't really understand:

```
b"H\x00\x84\xffQ\x00\xa6\xff+\x00\x96\xff\xc2\xffI\xff\xa5\xff'\xff\x8a\xff\x19\xff\x19\xff\xf6\xfe\xb0\xfe\xc7\xfeJ\xfel\xfe\xf8\xfd+\xfe\xef\xfd:\xfe\xc3\xfd*\xfe_\xfd\xdf\xfd\n\xfd\xa3\xfd\xc6\xfcq\xfd\xbd\xfc?\xfd"
```

So according to what I know, bytes should be represented as \xhh, where hh are hexadecimal values (from 0 to f). However, in the third segment, there is \xffQ, and farther on there are other characters which shouldn't appear: I, ', *, :, ? etc.
I've used hex() method to see what would be the outcome, and I got this:

```
480084ff5100a6ff2b0096ffc2ff49ffa5ff27ff8aff19ff19fff6feb0fec7fe4afe6cfef8fd2bfeeffd3afec3fd2afe5ffddffd0afda3fdc6fc71fdbdfc3ffd
```

As you can see, some parts of the hex are the same, but e.g. \xffQ was changed into ff51. I need to append some data to this byte string, so I'd like to know what's going on there (or how to get the same result).

Comment: Only unprintable characters are encoded using `\x__`, others are just shown as ASCII characters.

Comment: `bytes` are represented in printable characters where possible. `0x51` is the ASCII value for `Q`.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I think I know what to do then :)

Comment: If there's a canonical answer for this, I can't find it, but this question does come up periodically (ex.: [recent question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73113366/python-struct-not-accepting-0xf031-as-unsigned-short))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *repr* and *str* when processing a bytes object will print ASCII characters where possible. Otherwise their hexadecimal values will be shown in the form \xNN.

It might help you to visualise the content if you print it as all hexadecimal as follows:

```
b = b"H\x00\x84\xffQ\x00\xa6\xff+\x00\x96\xff\xc2\xffI\xff\xa5\xff'\xff\x8a\xff\x19\xff\x19\xff\xf6\xfe\xb0\xfe\xc7\xfeJ\xfel\xfe\xf8\xfd+\xfe\xef\xfd:\xfe\xc3\xfd*\xfe_\xfd\xdf\xfd\n\xfd\xa3\xfd\xc6\xfcq\xfd\xbd\xfc?\xfd"
print(''.join(hex(b_) for b_ in b))
```

**Output:**

```
0x480x00x840xff0x510x00xa60xff0x2b0x00x960xff0xc20xff0x490xff0xa50xff0x270xff0x8a0xff0x190xff0x190xff0xf60xfe0xb00xfe0xc70xfe0x4a0xfe0x6c0xfe0xf80xfd0x2b0xfe0xef0xfd0x3a0xfe0xc30xfd0x2a0xfe0x5f0xfd0xdf0xfd0xa0xfd0xa30xfd0xc60xfc0x710xfd0xbd0xfc0x3f0xfd
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) module if you want to visualize the content:

```
import binascii 
print(binascii.hexlify(b"hello world"))
```

**Output:**

```
68656c6c6f20776f726c64
```